# Why is font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero not working with my google font?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face

This is not producing a slashed 0 on my end:

```
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
  <style>
    h2{
      font-family: 'Inter';
      font-variant-numeric: slashed-zero;
    }
  </style>
  <h2>00000</h2>
```

I have tried searching for answers and could not find a straight up answer just yet. Also when I install the font I don't see a variant for the 0.

Comment: The font has to contain a glyph for the opentype `zero` character. If you look through the glyphs of that particular font, it doesn't contain one, so it can't respond to the font-variant. `font-variant-numeric` is still a relatively new CSS rule and as such it is not widely available for all Google Web Fonts. I would recommend picking a font which just includes a slashed zero as the default zero glyph like Roboto Mono.

Comment: I've opened an issue against the [rsms/inter GitHub repository](https://github.com/rsms/inter) in relation to this: [Include slashed zero in the Inter font available through Google Fonts #403](https://github.com/rsms/inter/issues/403)